# .Click not work with some IDs in a site by many ways

Tags: javascript, jquery, click

I create a javascript file to click a button on site (not my site, just create as a chrome extention). I tested on Chrome Script snippet but with some IDs, it worked and others not. Could someone give your help
!
Here is example javascript codes I used:

```
document.getElementById('__item3').click();
```

.

```
$('#__item3').click();
```

.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(#__item3').trigger('click');});
```

Here is example worked ID (__item3 - drop down a menu):

```
<a id="__item3" data-ui="__item3" tabindex="0" role="button" aria-describedby="__item3-describedby" title="My Menu" class="UshellShellHeadItm">
 <span class="UshellShellHeadItmCntnt" style="font-family: My-icons;">♡</span>
</a>
```

Here is example not work IDs (idArisBut - select a tab,__button7 - expand a list):

```
<li id="idArisBut" data-ui="idArisBut" aria-checked="false" class="MSegBBtn MSegBBtnFocusable" style="width: 33.3333%;">
 <div class="MSegBBtnInner">Process</div>
</li>
```

.

```
<button id="__button7" data-ui="__button7" aria-describedby="__button7-tooltip" tittle="Settings" class="MBtnBase MBtn MBarChid">
 <span id="__button7-inner" class="MBtnInner MBtnHoverable MFocusable MBtnIconFirst MBtnDefault">
 <span id="__button7-img" data-ui="__button7-img" role="presentation" aria-hiden="true" data-ui-icon-content="◇" class="UiIcon UiIconMirrorInRTL MBtnCustomIcon MBtnIcon MBtnIconLeft" style="font-family: 'Ico\2dicons';"></span></span>
</button>
```

Maybe some reasons? Thanks!

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're asking, but the native `click()` and jQuery's `click()` methods have different effects depending on how the event handler you're looking to trigger was bound to the element.

Comment: It may not be the `li id=idArisBut` that has the click handler - it could be bubbling up from `MSegBBtnInner`.   It might not be a `click` event - it could be mousedown/mouseup.  As in the comment above, without knowing more about how the event was attached, it's a guess at best.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, onclick worked with idArisBut, __button7 but click() is not.